# jQuery to cycle up and down select list values

Tags: jquery, list, select

This should be really simple with jQuery but I cant get it to work! Cant seem to find anything on searches either ...

I have a select list, and I want to use + and - buttons next to it (like quantity boxes) to cycle through the list values, so the user does not need to click the dropdown, scroll and select.

Effectively I need a select list, with 'next' and 'previous' buttons that simply fire jQuery on click and cycle up and down the values.

A bit sample script would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following `<html/>`

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Opion 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opion 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opion 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opion 4</option>
    <option value="5">Opion 5</option>
    <option value="6">Opion 6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value=" - " id="down"/>
<input type="button" value=" + " id="up"/>
```

And the script:

```
$("#up").click(function(){
    $("select option:selected").next().prop("selected", true);
});
$("#down").click(function(){
    $("select option:selected").prev().prop("selected", true);
});
```

*Note*, this relies on jQuery 1.6 and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), if using less than 1.6 use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/RXuTX/)**

Comment: I am using jqtransform to style the forms, and with this turned on the events will not fire - so I assume must be a selector issue?

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. I've forked your fiddle and made it cycle "around the clock". Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/lazurski/LQ58L/2/

Answer (score 0):

When the previous button is clicked, execute something like this:

```
var curr = $('#select').find(':selected');
var prev = curr.prev('option');
if (prev.length) {
    curr.removeAttr('selected');
    prev.attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

For the next button, it's almost identical:

```
var curr = $('#select').find(':selected');
var next= curr.next('option');
if (next.length) {
    curr.removeAttr('selected');
    next.attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set-up an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prMm2/1/

Basically, you just need to find the current selected element, remove it's selected state and add `selected="selected"` to the next one / previous one.